# if $X_n\rightarrow L$, then it can be considered a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: calculus

if $X_n\rightarrow L$, then it can be considered a Cauchy sequence?
I do familiar with the formal definition of Cauchy sequence which says that a sequence is Cauchy iff $$\forall \varepsilon  > 0\exists N.\forall m,n > N.d({x_n} - {x_m}) < \varepsilon $$

Is my claim right?

Comment: Yes. Use: $|x_n-x_m|\le|x_n-L|+|x_m-L|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Since $x_n\to \ell$ then for $\epsilon>0$ there's $N$ and if $n\ge N$ we have $d(x_n,\ell)<\epsilon$.

Now for $m\ge N$ we have
$$d(x_n,x_m)\le d(x_n,\ell)+d(x_m,\ell)\le2\epsilon$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes. Thank you Sami

Comment: You're welcome AndrePoole!

Comment: You give great hints, Sami!